# ROS2 string repr of parameter within launch file

Tags: python, ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to get `string` representation of parameter? `LaunchConfiguration('arg_name')` returns `LaunchConfiguration` object, while I need `string` to perform several actions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382028/ros2-string-repr-of-parameter-within-launch-file/) by [definitive](https://answers.ros.org/users/57454/definitive/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2021-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's automatically evaluated in the launch phase, so generally, you don't have to care about it.

If you'd like to print the value for debugging, you can use `OpaqueFunction`.
Related: https://answers.ros.org/question/322636/ros2-access-current-launchconfiguration/

I put a minimal example here.

```
# false
$ ros2 launch sample.launch.py use_sim_time:=false
use_sim_time: false

$ ros2 param get /publisher use_sim_time 
Boolean value is: False

# true
$ ros2 launch sample.launch.py use_sim_time:=true
use_sim_time: true

$ ros2 param get /publisher use_sim_time 
Boolean value is: True
```

The launch file is:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, OpaqueFunction
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node, SetParameter


def launch_setup(context, *args, **kwargs):
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration("use_sim_time")
    print(f"use_sim_time: {use_sim_time.perform(context)}")
    set_use_sim_time = SetParameter(name="use_sim_time", value=use_sim_time)

    node = Node(
        package="examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher",
        executable="publisher_lambda",
        name="publisher",
    )

    return [
        set_use_sim_time,
        node,
    ]


def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            DeclareLaunchArgument("use_sim_time", default_value="false"),
            OpaqueFunction(function=launch_setup),
        ]
    )
```

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2021-08-23**:
Thanks for providing the example @Kenji! It works perfectly.